# HTML5 submit button not working due to action attribute?

Tags: php, html, submit, action

i stumbled upon a problem I cannot resolve. I made this small contact form in HTML5 as shown below and
want to send the form via a submit button. No matter what I do the button does not response. As far as I know the action attribute is no longer needed for triggering the php code that I put above the header of my index.php. Could someone take a quick look and possibly guide me to a possible solution? I so far tried to put the mailer in a separate php-file but the button keeps unresponsive. Is there something I am missing? Thanks a lot!

```
<?php

### Setting up the contact formular ###

# send mail to whom?
$strEmpfaenger = 'michael.schwark@googlemail.com';

# has been sent from?
$strFrom       = '"omigretchen.de" <service@omigretchen.de>';

# with which subject?
$strSubject    = 'Mensaje www.omigretchen.de';

# where to go for success message?
$strReturnhtml = 'http://www.omigretchen.de/danke.html';

# which seperators to use in the email body?
$strDelimiter  = ":\t";

### Ende Konfiguration ###

if($_POST)
{

 if($_POST['NOMBRE'] && $_POST['EMAIL'] && $_POST['TELEFONO'])
{
 $strMailtext = "";

 while(list($strName,$value) = each($_POST))
 {
  if(is_array($value))
  {
   foreach($value as $value_array)
   {
    $strMailtext .= $strName.$strDelimiter.$value_array."\n";
   }
  }
  else
  {
   $strMailtext .= $strName.$strDelimiter.$value."\n";
  }
 }

}
 else $strReturnhtml = 'http://www.omigretchen.de/problem.php';

 if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
 {
  $strMailtext = stripslashes($strMailtext);
 }

 mail($strEmpfaenger, $strSubject, $strMailtext, "From: ".$strFrom)
  or die("No se puede enviar un email.");
 header("Location: $strReturnhtml");
 exit;
}

?>

<div id="formulario"><form id="form" class="form" name="form" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete>
<h1>¿Como podemos ayudarle?</h1>
<div class="content">
    <div class="intro">Si no le hemos llamado plazo de 24 horas por favor llame al: 611 392 38.</div>
    <div id="section1" >
        <div class="field"><label for="NOMBRE">NOMBRE</label><input id="NOMBRE" name="NOMBRE" type="text"></div>
        <div class="field"><label for="TELEFONO">TELÉFONO</label><input id="TELEFONO" name="TELEFONO" required type="tel"></div>
        <div class="field"><label for="EMAIL">EMAIL</label><input id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL" type="email"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="section2" >
        <div class="field"><div class="edit-options"><div class="edit"></div><div class="delete"></div></div><label for="Deseo"></label><textarea id="Deseo" name="Deseo" placeholder="¿Como podemos ayudarle?" wrap="hard"></textarea></div>
        <div class="field"><label for="Submit"></label><input id="Submit" value="Envíenos su consulta" name="Submit" type="submit"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</form></div></div>
```

Comment: I copied the form HTML into a new document, entered some data and hit submit. The button responded and the form submitted. I can't reproduce your problem from the code you've provided.

Comment: That is absolutely strange. No browser I use lets me send the form. The button switches color on hover, shows the border design but does not send. Something is going terribly wrong. Could you do me a favor and try this on my live site? http://www.omigretchen.de/ Maybe it is something completely else. I am totally lost :(.

Comment: Clicking the button causes errors to appear in the JavaScript console. Try reading them.

Comment: You are right. I have also been using the console: it gives me a "TypeError: full_url is undefined". Unfortunalety I cannot come across what url it is referring to. As far as I know action in HTML5 is deprecated and I do not know whereto it points me! Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Thanks, I was using Forefox console. I now can see that this points me to my scrollto function. Though this is getting weirder and weirder. Why would an input element defined to post want to call this function. I was wondering whether there is a missing closing div but there isnt. Thank you, one step closer though really strange!

Comment: Thanks Quentin, got it figured out. I made some changes in my setting.js last night and entering a wrong div to be triggered there seemingly caused confusion. Thanks to you I am three steps ahead. Saludos!